# Does $\operatorname{Var} (\varepsilon_i | X_i) = \operatorname{Var} (\varepsilon_j | X_j)$ follow from the first two assumptions of OLS estimator?

Tags: multiple-regression, least-squares

Let

$$X_i=\begin{pmatrix} X_{i_1} \\
X_{i_2} \\
\vdots \\
X_{i_K} \\
\end{pmatrix}, \qquad \beta=\begin{pmatrix} \beta_1 \\
\beta_2 \\
\vdots \\
\beta_K\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

I'm learning OLS estimator's assumptions:

- A0: $Y_i = X_i' \beta +\varepsilon_i$ for all $i=1,...,n$.
- A1: $\{(Y_i,\, X_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ are i.i.d.

Could you please confirm if my understanding is correct?

> By A0, $\varepsilon_i = Y_i - X_i' \beta$. By A1, $\{(Y_i - X_i' \beta,\,X_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ are i.i.d. Hence $\{(\varepsilon_i,\, X_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ are i.i.d. As such, $\operatorname{Var} (\varepsilon_i \,|\, X_i) = \operatorname{Var} (\varepsilon_j \,|\, X_j)$ for all $i,j = 1,...,n$.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Are A0 and A1 all the assumptions?

Comment: Hi @Jim, there are other assumptions too, but I'm not sure if I can deduce the $\operatorname{Var} (\varepsilon_i \,|\, X_i) = \operatorname{Var} (\varepsilon_j \,|\, X_j)$ from only A0 and A1.